# Can I use an std::ostream to print into a given buffer?

Tags: c++, c++11, formatting, ostream, c++23

I have a given buffer of characters (maybe even the buffer backing an `std::string`, but never mind that). I want to print into that buffer using an `std::ostream`, i.e. I want to be able to write:

```
span<char> my_buffer = get_buffer();
auto my_os = /* magic */;
static_assert(
   std::is_base_of<std::basic_ostream<char>,decltype(my_os)>::value,
   "magic failed");
my_os << "hello" << ',' << 123 << '\0';
std::cout << my_buffer << '\n';
```

and get:

```
hello,123
```

on the standard output.

Note: C++11 if possible, and please mention the language standard you're using. (And yes, I know C++11 doesn't have spans.)

Comment: Seems you are looking for [spanstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_spanstream) which, unfortunately, is C++23.

Comment: You need a corresponding streambuf implementation, so C++23. But an ostream can write into any valid streambuf.

Comment: @BoP you can write your own spanstream

Comment: @user253751: I'm sure someone has already done this... link perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Thank @BoP and @T.C. for the two parts of this solution)

This can be done... if you're willing to use a deprecated C++ construct: [`std:ostrstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream/ostrstream).

```
#include <strstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const size_t n = 20;
    char my_buffer[n];
    std::ostrstream my_os(my_buffer, n);
    my_os << "hello" << ',' << 123 << '\0';
    std::cout << my_buffer << '\n';
}
```

Notes about this code:

1. It [works](https://godbolt.org/z/noYao7Eaq) (GodBolt)
2. It is valid C++98! ... of course I had to let go of `std::span`, `auto` type inference etc. It's also valid C++11 and later standards.
3. This will construct an [`std::strstreambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstreambuf/strstreambuf), which is what an `std::ostrstream` uses directly, from your buffer of chars.

([see this on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/f5zTc54P5))

Unfortunately, with the deprecation of `std::ostrstream`, we were left with no fully-valid alternative up to, and including, C++20. You would need to implement a custom [`std::basic_streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), and assign it to an `std::ostream`. :-(

But in **C++23** - you are luck!  The standard library does offer *exactly* what you asked for: [`std::spanstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_spanstream/basic_spanstream): A `std::ostream` backed by a span of `char`'s which it is given at construction.

Comment: @T.C.: Can you elaborate on how I would use it with my own buffer?

Comment: The second constructor in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream/ostrstream

Comment: @T.C.: See edit.

Comment: `ostrstream` is very much a subclass of `ostream` (the `static_assert` in the question is backwards).

Comment: @T.C.: Corrected.